# Cherrypy : Do I really need to put it behind a frontend?

Tags: nginx, lighttpd, cherrypy, frontend

I've been working on a python web app using cherrypy and read it'd be more "robust" to use it as a backend, so I gave it a try.

Shortly put, running some benchmarks on a page doing some database operations and serving static & dynamic content has shown that plain cherrypy was twice as fast than nginx and memcached, and about half faster than lighttpd. I heard the latter had memory leak issues, so refrained from using it. And yes, both nginx and lighttpd were configured to serve the static content.

I didn't want to try out apache since I'll be deploying it on a relatively "small" VPS.

So, considering that :

- I wont' be deploying it on a
  distributed system for a while, is it
  safe to use cherrypy on its own ?
- And when I will deploy it on a such
  system, which frontend performs the
  best ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes; it's safe to use CherryPy on its own.

Comment: How does it deal with slow clients?

Comment: The socket timeout is configurable